# Visual Basic pulling a character from a certain line number

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a macro that needs to be able to check and make sure that a character on a certain line is what it should be before it finishes the form.

Where or how do i find the information to do this?

I have tried using the command `"Left(#of line ,1)"` and am not getting it to return anything at this point.

Comment: Is this a Visual Studio macro? or?

Comment: In .Net Left() above would be stringName.Substring(0,1)

Comment: IT IS NOT FOR VISUAL STUDIO. I AM WORKING ON A MACRO FOR PROP SOFTWARE. I NEED FOR THE MACRO TO CONTINUE ONE WAY IF THE FIRST CHAR OF LINE 9 IS A ">" AND ANOTHER IF NOT.

Comment: Without knowing what the proprietary software is and its macro language, we cannot give definitive help. Nevertheless, if you showed us more code around where you are having the problem, we may be able to figure something out for you. And if you SHOUT at us, you may scare us off.

Comment: Sorry about that. Most of the work I do has to be done in caps and I forgot till I sent it. I did get this worked out. Thank you for your help all.

Answer (score 0):

I Assume that you have this *text* in a string. Comment to my answer if wrong.
You can use a Regex to compare to string with your character like so :

```
If Regex.IsMatch(MyString, *.{X}Y) Then
'You have to manually replace X for the number of characters before the character you scan for
'You have to manually replace Y for the-said character it is supposed to be
```

Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial for more info on Regex.

If you want to only take one line in your string :

```
TheLine = split(MyString,Environnement.Newline)([Line Number])
```

Comment: The code currently is: `If (Left(ReadLine(9), 1)) = "$" Then .Transmit "P" '& CR ElseIf (Left(ReadLine(9), 1)) <> "$" Then .Transmit "no p" ' & CR End If –`

Comment: From where do you read the line? You have to specify from where it comes. The function `ReadLine` needs to point to something. Like : `FileName.ReadLine`or `MyString.ReadLine`. And instead of using `Left` (as it doesn't work) I suggest trying `Regex.Ismatch(MyString.ReadLine(9), ^A)`which does TRUE if the line starts with "A".